# How to calculate the value of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n^a}$, where $a > 1$?

Tags: calculus

As stated above, I want to know how to calculate $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^a}$, where $a>1$? Or can you tell me if there is a general method to calculate it? Thank you!

Comment: Title expression is different from body.  Anyway, cf. [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function)

Comment: $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^a}=\zeta(a), \text{Re}(a)>1$$

Comment: @  J. W. Tanner I have corrected it in the body. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: There are methods to calculate numerical approximations, and we know $\zeta(2n)$ for even integers $2n$ in terms of $\pi$ and Bernoulli numbers. The value of $\zeta(3)$ is known as Apery's constant. There is evidence from the theory of "periods" (as a generalization of algebraic numbers) that $\zeta(2n-1)$ for odd numbers $2n-1$ is not expressible as a rational multiple of a power of pi.

Answer (score 3):

As J.W. Tanner said, for values $a>1$ you can use the [Riemann Zeta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function)

Particularly, when $a>1$ you get that the integral

$$ \zeta(s) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-x} \mathrm{d}x$$
converges to the sum that you want to calculate,
and $\Gamma(s)$ is the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

If you're just looking for a way to evaluate the sum, you can write a program which approximates the integral using a Riemann Sum, which in turn will evaluate your infinite sum.